# assign value to div returning from JSON result

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have one div whois id is generated in php in one loop.

```
    <div align="left" id="BalBox<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" 
class="text_balance">Balance: 
    </div>
```

where **pid** will be 1, 2, 3 etc

now i have JSON as bellow, in this JSON second optionDisplay is actually **pid** and first optionValue is value after calculation in php file.

```
    [{optionValue:12, optionDisplay:1},{optionValue:0, optionDisplay:2}
,{optionValue:0, optionDisplay:3},]
```

now what i need is,

Display 12 on BalBox1 , as optionDisplay:1 is for BalBox and optionValue is for value, so now value of BalBox1 will be Balance: 12, same like this for all in JSON result.

here is my jquery code..

```
$.getJSON("page.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
     var options = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
       $('#BalBox'+j[i].optionDisplay).val("Balance: " +j[i].optionValue);
     }
```

but its not working...
i mean its not showing or changing any thing...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erm. did you alert the values of `j` to check if they're set?

and you should use `.html()` instead of `.val()` since you're trying to edit DIV's and not INPUT's

cheers :)